# Applications not seeing Android

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I am running 20.04 with KDE desktop. Applications no longer see my phone when connected to the computer. I had Lollypop syncing with my phone now it no longer sees it. As well Calibre cant see it or connect via content server or wireless. I can see the phone in Dolphin and access files. The phone has USB debugging allowed and is connected to as a MTP when connected.

I am at a loss..

Thanks

Comment: Are lollypop and Calibre installed as snap apps? Can other apps installed with apt see your phone?